# Xcode 10 beta2: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIView' with no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

I have downloaded Xcode 10 beta2 and rebuild my project, codes such as:

```
let someView = UIView()
```

come up with the following error:

`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIView' with no arguments`

[image: Error Snapshort]

Pretty strange. Has anybody encountered those building errors when using Xcode 10 beta2?

Comment: I'm not using Xcode 10 yet but note that `UIView` never actually defined a no-argument initializer. That was inherited from `NSObject`. You have always been expected to use `UIView(frame:)`.

Comment: Hmm.  I cannot reproduce that error with Xcode 10 beta 2.

Comment: In my opinion it's *pretty strange* that the compiler tolerated the nonsensical usage of the default initializer so far . Congrats to the Swift team for fixing that.

Comment: Any fix for that problem?

Comment: @ironRoei Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55232915/1954737)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging I have finally found the problem.

I use a pod [SwiftTheme](https://github.com/jiecao-fm/SwiftTheme), after upgrading it to a new version those errors have gone.

[image]

See this [commit](https://github.com/jiecao-fm/SwiftTheme/commit/2030c5d5443eba722f157fe2bc1a6265c83af30d#diff-c4556259fad2a7d4d5c3f4558e2eab46).

Answer (score 1):

For me it was reasoned by extending NSObjectProtocol:

```
extension NSObjectProtocol where Self: UIView
```

I fixed it by replacing NSObjectProtocol to any other protocol that UIView conforms. In my case it was UIAppearance:

```
extension UIAppearance where Self: UIView
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let someView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Just add the "frame" argument:
UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
(or whatever you need it to be)

In my code I set up the Views like this and later I add constraints (which basically override frame parameters).

The same works for UIView, UILabel, UIScrollView and others...
For UIButtons, add the "type" argument instead:
UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)