# Xcode won't let me use NSObject's init() function for UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It might be very similar to this still-opened question: [Xcode 10 beta2: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIView' with no arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124370/xcode-10-beta2-cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-uiview-with-no-arguments)

**Issue:**

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIImageView' with no arguments

But kindly please give me a chance to ask this. I have a project that is written in Swift 4.0 previously and suddenly Xcode won't let me make a `UIView` object with `NSObject`'s `init()` method. Just all of a sudden.

**What I already did:**

1. I switched back to a working commit, and boy, project won't still compile.
2. Of course I tried compiling my other projects and of course they compiled while having so many views constructed with `UIView()`.
3. Tried search for answers, but then again the question linked above does not have an answer.
4. Currently doing a comparison between this project's project settings against a new project's.

**What I want to ask and want to know:**

1. I need to know, cause this is quite bothering, why this happens.
2. Is this a configuration error in Xcode? But I somehow doubt that because I already switched to a working commit and it still has compile-time errors.

Please don't tell me to use `UIView(frame: CGRect)` constructor, as I have hundreds of `UIView()` code, and similar code.

**What I do know:**

[Where does UIView.init() come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434614/where-does-uiview-init-come-from)

> Keep in mind that UIView is an Objective-C class, and Objective-C is
>   not Swift. None of the rules about designated and convenience
>   initializers and the rules of their inheritance exist in Objective-C —
>   a fact that can sometimes cause significant trouble when using those
>   classes in Swift. That said, in effect, UIView's init() is a
>   convenience initializer that calls init(frame: .zero).

Thanks!

Comment: Swift classes don't automatically inherit parent initializers if the class declares one or more of its own initializers. `UIView` has its own initializers and the empty one is no longer one of them. Even in Objective-C, the empty initializer is not in `UIView`. It comes from `NSObject` as you know. But Objective-C classes inherit parent initializers no matter what. In reality, the empty initializer for a `UIView` in either language was never correct, even if it used to work.

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment on the link I provided above. However, I still want to know how to get rid of the nuisance. Why one project compiles and this one does not. Is there a config to toggle to enable UIView to use NSObject's empty initializer? Just an answer how to do that will suffice.

Comment: I believe it's a function of the project's Base SDK.

Comment: BTW - it would be best to fix your code. Some good use of Xcode's search and replace should make the changes fairly quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this thread/question, I'll add an answer.

I wasn't the one who solved this. This project, if not mentioned in the question, is merely a side project, from a remote/freelance work. I was actually, if not mentioned above too, migrating the project to Swift 4.2. Along the way, this issue came up. I didn't bother to rename all the pieces of codes to be renamed during the update. Long story short, I gave up on this task for a bit, but someone in the company decided to solve it.

The solution is: **finish the migration first**. Just rename all the stuff that is needed for Swift 4.2, and update the pods as well. That's it! :) I hope this helps people in the future.